# Caddy server stop working with error "Stopped background certificate maintenance "

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

I am facing an issue with CaddyServer. It stop working. I find a message " Stopped background certificate maintenance "

I run `npm run build` command in a nuxt2 project. then caddy automatically down.

How:

My Package.json code below:

```
{
  "name": "uihut",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "export": "nuxt export",
    "serve": "nuxt serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.11.0",
    "@nuxtjs/robots": "^2.5.0",
    "@nuxtjs/sitemap": "^2.4.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "hooper": "^0.3.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.13.0",
    "slugify": "^1.5.0",
    "v-wow": "^1.2.1",
    "view-design": "^4.5.0",
    "vue-clickaway": "^2.2.2",
    "vue-lazyload": "^1.3.3",
    "vue-masonry-wall": "^0.3.2",
    "vue-sweetalert2": "^5.0.5",
    "vue-typed-js": "^0.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/postcss8": "^1.1.3",
    "@nuxtjs/google-analytics": "^2.4.0",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.5",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5",
    "node": "^16.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7"
  }
}
```

Caddy error:

```
Feb 06 17:58:57 staging-server caddy[58600]: {"level":"info","ts":1675706337.0468912,"logger":"http.acme_client","msg":"validations succeeded; finalizing order","order":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/order/952014366/163268940>
Feb 06 17:58:57 staging-server caddy[58600]: {"level":"info","ts":1675706337.7899773,"logger":"http.acme_client","msg":"successfully downloaded available certificate chains","count":2,"first_url":"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acm>
Feb 06 17:58:57 staging-server caddy[58600]: {"level":"info","ts":1675706337.7907612,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"certificate obtained successfully","identifier":"utm.besnik.net"}
Feb 06 17:58:57 staging-server caddy[58600]: {"level":"info","ts":1675706337.790849,"logger":"tls.obtain","msg":"releasing lock","identifier":"utm.besnik.net"}
Feb 06 17:59:02 staging-server caddy[58600]: {"level":"info","ts":1675706342.5809731,"logger":"admin.api","msg":"received request","method":"POST","host":"localhost:2019","uri":"/stop","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","remote_port":"39336","heade>
Feb 06 17:59:02 staging-server caddy[58600]: {"level":"warn","ts":1675706342.5811977,"logger":"admin.api","msg":"exiting; byeee!! "}
Feb 06 17:59:02 staging-server caddy[58600]: {"level":"info","ts":1675706342.5815964,"logger":"tls.cache.maintenance","msg":"stopped background certificate maintenance","cache":"0xc0001e1730"}
Feb 06 17:59:02 staging-server caddy[58600]: {"level":"info","ts":1675706342.581959,"logger":"admin","msg":"stopped previous server","address":"localhost:2019"}
Feb 06 17:59:02 staging-server caddy[58600]: {"level":"info","ts":1675706342.5819852,"logger":"admin.api","msg":"shutdown complete","exit_code":0}
Feb 06 17:59:02 staging-server systemd[1]: caddy.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stop daemon Service:
`sudo systemctl stop caddy.service`

Then Disable :
`sudo systemctl disable caddy.service`

Then Enable:
`sudo systemctl enable caddy.service`

Reload all daemon:
`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

After that caddy will work.